# ngRepeat across pairs to build table with rowspan="2"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I have an array of pairs that I need to display in a table where the 1st column spans 2 rows like in the image.

The array looks like this:

```
$scope.products = [{
    p0: {name: "n1", img: "a", brand: "apple", desc: "1"},
    p1: {name: "n2", img: "b", brand: "apple", desc: "2"}
},{
    p0: {name: "n3", img: "c", brand: "apple", desc: "3"},
    p1: {name: "n4", img: "d", brand: "apple", desc: "4"}
},{
    p0: {name: "n5", img: "e", brand: "apple", desc: "5"},
    p1: {name: "n6", img: "f", brand: "apple", desc: "6"}
},{
    p0: {name: "n7", img: "g", brand: "apple", desc: "7"},
    p1: {name: "n8", img: "h", brand: "apple", desc: "8"}
}];
```

The "hardcoded" version of this would be

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Product name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">a b</th>
        <td>apple</td>
        <td>n1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>apple</td>
        <td>n2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">c d</th>
        <td>apple</td>
        <td>n3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>apple</td>
        <td>n4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know how I can achieve this with an ng-repeat. I tried something silly like the code below but obviously it didn't work.
Help?

```
<div ng-repeat="pair in products">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">{{pair.p0.img}} {{pair.p1.img}}</th>
        <td>{{pair.p0.brand}}</td>
        <td>{{pair.p0.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{pair.p1.brand}}</td>
        <td>{{pair.p1.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you use a cunstruction like:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="...">
   <tr>...</tr>
   ...
</tbody>
```

in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert two tr element inside table for every record right?

You can use tag `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);
      app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.products = [{
            p0: { name: "n1", img: "a", brand: "apple", desc: "1" },
            p1: { name: "n2", img: "b", brand: "apple", desc: "2" }
        }, {
            p0: { name: "n3", img: "c", brand: "apple", desc: "3" },
            p1: { name: "n4", img: "d", brand: "apple", desc: "4" }
        }, {
            p0: { name: "n5", img: "e", brand: "apple", desc: "5" },
            p1: { name: "n6", img: "f", brand: "apple", desc: "6" }
        }, {
            p0: { name: "n7", img: "g", brand: "apple", desc: "7" },
            p1: { name: "n8", img: "h", brand: "apple", desc: "8" }
        }];
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="yourApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Product name</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">a b</th>
            <td>apple</td>
            <td>n1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>apple</td>
            <td>n2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">c d</th>
            <td>apple</td>
            <td>n3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>apple</td>
            <td>n4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat-start="pair in products"></tr>
              <th rowspan="2">{{pair.p0.img}} {{pair.p1.img}}</th>
              <td>{{pair.p0.brand}}</td>
              <td>{{pair.p0.name}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>{{pair.p1.brand}}</td>
              <td>{{pair.p1.name}}</td>
          <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I've added a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QJEo5sv9N3HnBYvyb1Ne?p=preview)